# Django DateField and Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I'm using SQLite for development, but when deploying to production (using Postgres), I had the following error on a CreateView:

```
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
operator does not exist: character varying = date
LINE 1: ...xxxx" WHERE "xxxxx"."date" = '2019-07...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

This is the field:

```
date = models.DateField('Date', max_length=150, default='', blank=True, unique=True)
```

Also, I use this in settings.py:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Do you have any ideas ?

EDIT:
This is the code where I list the objects after their creation:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ObjectListView, self).get_queryset().filter(topic__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
```

Comment: give your code where you apply query on date field.

Comment: I dropped the database and created a new one. Now it works without problems.

Comment: yaa..it's work i was found that solution and it's working after drop databse because of some version problem

Comment: sorry I didn't understand your comment. But I think it may be related to postgres version